# FDC1004 - Connection (Texas Instruments)

Tags: measurement, capacitance

I am trying to figure out how to use an FDC1004 capacitance to digital converter with a capacitor. Actually there are no pin signs on the chip so I cannot understand what to connect where even though I have studied the related [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/fdc1004.pdf?ts=1668760578895&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F).

Anyone who has worked with that and can help?

Comment: what do you mean by `no pin signs`?

Comment: I mean is not written what to add and where

Comment: ok, I'm intrigued ... are you asking for a schematic diagram?

Comment: You sound a bit overwhelmed. Suggest you search for FDC1004 Design examples. TI has app notes and an evaluation board. Protocentral makes a low cost board with code on github.

Comment: *implementing capacitive sensing solutions* means a sensor for capacitive sensor applications with an input range of ±15 pF, which would make it not very useful for measuring capacitors.  Connect to any of CIN1 to CIN4.  It will mux between all 4,

Comment: YEs I am looking into a schematic design

Comment: I actually have this design in mind https://ibb.co/tpjhf8W

Should I just connect FDC1004 SDA, SCL, Vcc (3.3V), Gnd to Arduino and a capacitor on Cin1 between FDC1004 and Gnd??

Comment: Anyone who can help on that>?